# Amplify lambda function "Not Authorized to access [function] on type [model]"

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am following the explanations from this website: https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-mobile-app-part-two/module-four/

If I start the application, a profile is not created, which should be happening in "custom.js".

```
const { Sha256 } = require("@aws-crypto/sha256-js");
const { defaultProvider } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node");
const { SignatureV4 } = require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4");
const { HttpRequest } = require("@aws-sdk/protocol-http");
const { default: fetch, Request } = require("node-fetch");

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_AMPLIFYTRIPSPLANNER_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
const AWS_REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1';

const query = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation createProfile($email: String!,$owner: String!) {
    createProfile(input: {
      email: $email,
      owner: $owner,
      
    }) {
      email
    }
  }
`;




/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').PostConfirmationTriggerHandler}
 */
 exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);


  const variables = {
    
      email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
      owner: `${event.request.userAttributes.sub}::${event.userName}`
    
  };






  const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    sha256: Sha256
  });

  const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: endpoint.host
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
    path: endpoint.pathname
  });

  const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
  const request = new Request(endpoint, signed);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let body;
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    if (body.errors) statusCode = 400;
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 500;
    body = {
      errors: [
        {
          message: error.message
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  console.log(`statusCode: ${statusCode}`);
  console.log(`body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);

  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
};
```

I was expecting the profile to be created, when I run the application. But there is no profile created.

Cloud watch is providing this error log message:

```
{
    "data": {
        "createProfile": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "createProfile"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "Unauthorized",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 6,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "Not Authorized to access createProfile on type Profile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to understand the two problems:

1. The data should not be null
2. There should not be an authorization problem (which maybe a follow-on from the data issue)

I have not found any useful hints yet.

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realized my error. I did not follow the instructions to start the second tuturial within a clean directory. The Amplify configuration required a change in the Auth module, that can only be implemented in a new project (you cannot change auth type after deploying an app).